# Kendo UI - Turning Text() enclosed text into <span> encoded HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I am trying to add style to title of a panel bar that comes with Kendo UI
and I want to break this pure text of `Blah-1 Blah-2` into 2 span blocks so it outputs html as `<span>Blah-1</span>` and `<span>Blah -2</span>`

How do I achieve that with the following?

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
  .Name("panelBar")
  .Items(panelBar =>
  {
    panelBar.Add().Text("Blah-1 Blah-2")
  })
)
```

I've tried to encode `<span>` within `Text()` but it doesn't escape html tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Encode` method allows you to stop HTML encoding (done by default):

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
  .Name("panelBar")
  .Items(panelBar =>
  {
    panelBar.Add().Text("<span>Blah-1</span><span>Blah-2</span>").Encoded(false);
  })
)
```