# How to split text in a Kendo PanelBar?

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, panelbar

```
panelbar.Add()
        .Text(string.Format(Common_Formats.CopyRight, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"), Version.ToString())).
```

`Common_Formats.CopyRight` is a string read from the `.resx` file:

```
© {0}  ABC Systems Inc. <br> All rights reserved. V: {1}
```

I put `"<br>"` and `\n` in the text, still its not splitting.

Comment: Try putting | where the <br/> is and do: `LCL.Common_Formats.Shared_Footer_CopyRight.Replace("|", "<br/>")`   The panel bar may encode the <br/> to use &lt; instead of `<`, not 100% sure if that is what you are running into...

Comment: @Brian
© 2016 ABC Systems Inc. <br/> All rights reserved. V: 1.4.0.24
is the result

Comment: Meaning you can see `<br/>` literally, or it's producing the correct result?

Comment: its not producing the correct result :( , i can see the <br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this to turn off encoding, which essentially calls

```
.Encoded(false);
```

[Kendo UI - Turning Text() enclosed text into <span> encoded HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184242/kendo-ui-turning-text-enclosed-text-into-span-encoded-html)